# How to prevent errors in Manipulate with ListPlot when a result is an empty list?

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, manipulate

I am trying to plot two lists, where one is the reference list, and the other is only used to select and highlight the first list. Basically, I want to use the selection list `slist` to highlight different points in the reference list `reflist` after using `Manipulate`:

```
reflist = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, a}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -4, -1}, {z, 0, 5}, {a,0, 3}], 3];
slist = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, a}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -2, -2}, {z, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}],3];

Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[
   Select[reflist, #[[1]] == x && #[[2]] == y &][[All, 3 ;; 4]], 
   PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {"z", "a"}, PlotLabel -> {x, y}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False], 
  ListLinePlot[
   Select[slist, #[[1]] == x && #[[2]] == y &][[All, 3 ;; 4]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"z", "a"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Joined -> False]], {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, -4, -1, 1}]
```

Returns the following graph when x=1 and y=-2:
[image]

The problem occurs when `slist` has no point in common with `reflist`:
[image]

So my questions are:
1. Is there any way for me to avoid getting the error and just have **no point highlighted** when the two lists have no points in common, and **just show all points in black**?  2. I am also looking to highlight the whole regions where the points are (this would make a square in the first figure, with vertices in each red point). Is there any way to do it in `ListPlot`?

Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Manipulate[
   q = Select[slist, #[[1]] == x && #[[2]] == y &][[All, 3 ;; 4]]; 
   Show[ListPlot[Select[reflist, #[[1]] == x && #[[2]] == y &][[All, 3 ;; 4]], 
         PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {"z", "a"}, PlotLabel -> {x, y}, 
         PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False], 
       If[q == {}, {}, ListLinePlot[q, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"z", "a"}, 
         PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False]]], {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, -4, -1, 1}]
```

What this does is to test if the plot is going to be empty, if so, plot the empty set. If it's non-empty, plot the new one on top. Thanks to Istvan for the improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Answering also your second part:

> . I am also looking to highlight the whole regions where the points are (this would make a square in the first figure, with vertices in each red point)

```
reflist = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, a}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -4, -1}, {z, 0, 5}, {a,  0, 3}], 3];
slist =   Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, a}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -4, -2}, {z, 0, -y}, {a, 0, x}], 3];
<< ComputationalGeometry`
filter[list_, x_, y_] := If[#=={}, {Undefined[]},#] &@ Cases[list, {x, y, __}][[All, 3 ;; 4]]
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[{filter[reflist, x, y], filter[slist, x, y]}, 
               PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[Large], Black}, Red}, Joined -> False,
               AxesLabel -> {"z", "a"}, PlotLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All],
      If[# != {Undefined[]}, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[#, Polygon@ConvexHull[#]]], {}] &@
                                                                       filter[slist, x, y]], 
{x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, -4, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @belisarius, it works like a charm!